# Nuxt.js 3 - useAppConfig() returning unknown

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

In a NuxtJs 3 project I tried to add some specific stuff into my app.config.ts a the root directory of my project.

When I tried to call `useAppConfig()` to use my config data, VSCode raise an error `appConfig.as is unknown type`

I'm stuck with that :(

The `app.config.ts` :

```js
interface asAppConfig {
  layout: {
    nav: {
      isOpen: boolean
    }
  }
}

export default defineAppConfig({
  ui: {
    notifications: {
      position: 'top-0 right-0 bottom-auto',
    },
  },

  as: {
    layout: {
      nav: {
        isOpen: false,
      },
    },
  } satisfies asAppConfig,
})
```

Below after calling `useAppConfig()`, I have `appConfig.as is unknown type`

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>

  const appConfig = useAppConfig()

  const isOpen = computed({
    get: () => appConfig.as.layout.nav.isOpen,
    set: (value: boolean) => (appConfig.as.layout.nav.isOpen = value)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried using the `useAppConfig()` composable. But, based on the [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/app-config#typing-app-config), it says,

> Nuxt tries to automatically generate a TypeScript interface from
> provided app config so you won't have to type it yourself.
>
> However, there are some cases where you might want to type it
> yourself. There are two possible things you might want to type.

`~/index.d.ts`

```js
declare module 'nuxt/schema' {
  interface AppConfigInput {
    ui: {
      notifications: {
        position: string; // Assuming position can be any string
      };
    };
    as: {
      layout: {
        nav: {
          isOpen: boolean;
        };
      };
    };
  }
}

// It is always important to ensure you import/export something when augmenting a type
export { }
```

**Note:** Once you added that file, you might want to reload your IDE.

`~/app.config.ts`

```js
export default defineAppConfig({
  ui: {
    notifications: {
      position: 'top-0 right-0 bottom-auto',
    },
  },
  as: {
    layout: {
      nav: {
        isOpen: false,
      },
    },
  }
})
```

Now, it should show the available typings for you.
[image]

[image]

Again, I haven't used the `useAppConfig` composable. My answer is just based on the Nuxt documentation.

Comment: Thank's for your answer but this is not working for me :( 
I added the index.d.ts, with the right content, reload my IDE but I already have the same issue :(

Comment: Can you specify what issue you are experiencing?